# Expand and give focus to SearchView automatically

Tags: android, search, focus, expand

I'm developing an application where the user presses the "Search" icon in the `ActionBar` and a `SearchView` is made visible at the top of the screen.

My problem is that the `SearchView` is not in focus nor expanded so the user has to press the search button on the `Searchview` to make it expand and bring out the keyboard.

How should this be solved?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To make the SearchView expanded by default, call [setIconifiedByDefault(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView#attr_android:iconifiedByDefault) on it when you initialise it (e.g. in `onCreateOptionsMenu(..)` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu(..)`). I've found in most cases this will give it focus automatically, but if not simply call `requestFocus()` on it too.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, sorry.

Comment: Adding a `requestFocus()` call in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(..)` did the trick for me.

Comment: `requestFocus` doesn't work for me. To "focus" you can call `setIconified` with `false`

Comment: @SweSnow You have to set both ...searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.requestFocus();

Comment: be sure to have set the menu item property `app:showAsAction="always"`. When I removed the autofocus the icon disappeared and the 3 dots icon appeared

Answer (score 113):

You can also call to expandActionView() method in order to force it:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );

    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.mi_search ); // get my MenuItem with placeholder submenu
    searchMenuItem.expandActionView(); // Expand the search menu item in order to show by default the query

    return true;
}
```

Search item in the Action Bar layout:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/mi_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_search_api_holo_light"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
        />
```

Comment: If you use [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), instead of calling `expandActionView()` directly on the `searchMenuItem`, you should use this instead: `MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem)`.

Comment: @CharlesMadere way is the only one that worked for me, API 23

Comment: plus 1 for `searchMenuItem.expandActionView();`

Comment: MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem) is deprecated now

Comment: This solution is deprecated.

Comment: Finally, one using showAsAction(ifRoom|collapseActionView). Also, I had to add:

`searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)`

Answer (score 66):

If you want to have it `iconifiedByDefault`, this worked for me. `setFocusable` and `setIconified` are needed.

```
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setFocusable(true);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Update: If you are Using *`android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`* the behaviour us very different. `clearFocus` is needed if you don't want the keyboard pop-up all the time. For some reason the menu is recreated all the time, when using appcompat.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 28):

If you're using it in layout, you can call

`mSearchView.onActionViewExpanded()`

Comment: What does using in layout mean?

Comment: I mean that you reference to it as a `View`, not `MenuItem`

Comment: that didn't work for me.  Calling setIconified() did though.

Comment: worked for me too, I am not sure why in official website they have not included in sample code. I mean if i am clicking on search button the keyboard should open right???

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me :

In the root layout :

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

SearchView defined as follows :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view"        
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Search name or email"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

The difference is with app tag.

```
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
app:queryHint="Search name or email"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using inside an activity you need to use

```
view.onActionViewExpanded();
```

if you are using inside menu options you need to use

```
MenuItem.expandActionView();
```

Note: it works only for SearchView

these two situations are worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
menu.expandActionView();
```

Comment: but close icon is not visible initially in expanded form. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706192/how-to-display-searchview-close-icon-when-expanded-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SearchView#setIconified()` method on a SearchView handle in your Java code. More here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconified(boolean)

You can also make use of `SearchView#setIconifiedByDefault()`. More info here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconifiedByDefault(boolean)

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                SearchView searchView = new SearchView(mActivity.actionBar.getThemedContext());
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mActivity.getComponentName()));
                searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
                searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setActionView(searchView);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Pascalius's answer worked for me. But every time you close the SearchView, and click again, you lost the Focus. So I inserted the code in a `setOnMenuItemClickListener` like this:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For Appcompat Searchview you can use this method:

```
MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin**

```
var searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).actionView as SearchView
searchView.isIconified = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `expandActionView()` on the menuItem.

```
menuItem.expandActionView()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time doing this with `SearchView widget`, but the `expandActionView() method` is actually defined in the MenuItem class, not SearchView class. So, I solved it by

```
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
        SearchView   searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchItem.expandActionView();//the method expandActionView is called on searchItem not searchView
```

Answer (score 1):

"android.widget.SearchView" has different behavior from the other menu items. So you should use "setOnSearchClickListener", not "OnMenuItemClickListener" nor "onOptionsItemSelected".

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu_search_view);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    // Just like this!
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(view -> {
        view.requestFocus();
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MenuItemCompat's SearchView has a property named maxWidth.

```
final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
searchView.setMaxWidth(xxx);
```

use screen width instead of xxx offcourse

Answer (score 0):

I am using android.widget Searchview and iconified by default.Below code in xml helped me make it expand and autofocus on search view,when clicked:

```
<SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:queryHint="Search"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search the customer...");
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(Objects.requireNonNull(searchManager).getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.requestFocus();

    }
```

```html
<pre>

 <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search the customer...");
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(Objects.requireNonNull(searchManager).getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.requestFocus();

    }

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my usage combination:

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded(); //focus searchView
searchView.setQuery(searchKey, false); //set query

//Hide Keyboard
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

`android:iconifiedByDefault="true"`

Above is the code in XML helped me make it expand and autofocus on search view when clicked: