# How to expand SearchView attached to a view?

Tags: android, android-search

I want the default view of searchview in  expanded form, placed inside layout file.

my code...

**layout file:**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/rel2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/rel2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**Java src:**

```
search_view.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

There is other option like:
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235677/how-do-i-open-the-searchview-programmatically)
and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710042/expand-and-give-focus-to-searchview-automaticly)

both dosen't work for me.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question to make it more easy to understand.

Comment: I have edited my question just have a check. if still its not clear tell me which part is not clear.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#ConfiguringWidget

Comment: Is it in menu? if so, show the menu xml

Comment: It is not in menu, it is in layout file.