# How to display searchview close icon when expanded in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, searchview, android-search

I have an imageView. When i click image, i am hidding image and enabling searchview in expanded. But problem is close icon is not visible.
How to make close icon visible when searchview in expanded form?

Here is my piece of code:

```
  public class HomeActivity extends Activity{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
 search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_image);

  searchImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            search.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // here i am disabling default icon
            searchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

 //This function not works as close icon not visible.
     search.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            searchImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is screenshot where close icon at top right not visible:
[image]

Comment: Is this search view in Action bar ?

Comment: where is the close icon?

Comment: need to enable default behaviour of searchview close icon ie "x" icon. http://i.stack.imgur.com/HvE3u.png with expanded form. @Harish when i click imageview button. i can display in expanded form but x icon not displaying when i type text alone, it's displaying. i need to display in expanded form with close icon.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and he search view is on a toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute `app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_my_close_icon"` in your `SearchView` or `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

Use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
  searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: still same issue. x icon not displayed in expanded form.

Answer (score 0):

### the back option will display when you use[Complete concept about SearchView]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="blackmonk.mobile.activity.SearchActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_searchh"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

### and use

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_searchh);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_searchh)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search here");
    //to expand search bar
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:

        break;
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

### If you want to get Query String use this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String searchQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
}
```

## Dont forget to add this code in your Manifest Activity

```
  <activity
        android:name="blackmonk.mobile.activity.SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </action>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/search" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int search_close_btnId = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn;
ImageView search_close_btn = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(search_close_btnId);
search_close_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_search);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int searchCloseIconButtonId = SearchView.getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
    ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) this.mSearchView.findViewById(searchCloseIconButtonId);
    closeButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.close); //any icon image
```

If you want you can add click listener on `closeButton`

Answer (score 0):

Since SearchView always set Close button to `Gone` after onFocusChange, I did this in inelegant way.

```java
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
    Util.Android.scheduleRunOnUi(Util.Android.getActivity(view), ()->mCloseView.setVisibility(VISIBLE), 500);
}
```