# How to make SearchView on Toolbar always expanded?

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview, actionview

I already define `setIconified()` and `setIconifiedByDefault()` to false but the SearchView menu item is not expanding by default. Here's how I implemented it:

```
View customTitle = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_title, null);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_buddies);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setQueryHint("Search Buddies");
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

My menu_buddies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        xmlns:pawesome="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        pawesome:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        pawesome:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Post your XML file with `R.id.menu_search`

Comment: @dieter_h already posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand and give focus to SearchView automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710042/expand-and-give-focus-to-searchview-automatically)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the value of `android:showAsAction` to `always`. The SearchView's attribute `android:iconifiedByDefault should` be `true`.

Comment: this works, but how can i disable the collapsing of my searchview?

Comment: Collapse it with:

`searchView.setIconified(true);`

Comment: searchview is still collapsing. i want it to be always expanded @dieter_h

Comment: searchView.setIconified(false);
use this line for always expand.

Answer (score 3):

Have you solved this yet? 
Remove:

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

and keep only this line:

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

As well as showAsAction="always" in menu-xml.

This works for me, the searchview is expanded and can not be collapsed by any means.

Comment: Pressing the back button while the searchView is focused seems to close the searchview.

Comment: by this searchview not taking focus.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me.

Use this

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                SearchView searchView = new SearchView(mActivity.actionBar.getThemedContext());
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mActivity.getComponentName()));
                searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
                searchView.setQueryHint("search");
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setActionView(searchView);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you solve your issue, but here the recommendation for others
Just remove from menu_buddies i.e your menu item

```
pawesome:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

to this

```
pawesome:showAsAction="always"
```

cause collapseActionView make your searchview collapse, so again here the compelete menu item code ie. you menu_buddies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        xmlns:pawesome="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        pawesome:showAsAction="always"
        pawesome:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Note:
To make your searchView item from toolbar(either material toolbar or actionview) always expand make sure

1. In your menu item of searchview set

   app:showAsAction="always"
2. SearchView searchView = (SearchView)
   toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
   searchView.setIconified(false);
   searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

make sure setIconified and setIconifiedByDefault false that's it